# build_runner showing error The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

When I am running build_runner command it is showing me following error:

```
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_style-2.3.5/lib/src/front_end/ast_node_visitor.dart:251:16: Error: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'.
  - 'ClassDeclaration' is from 'package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.2.0/lib/src/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'macroKeyword'.
          node.macroKeyword,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_style-2.3.5/lib/src/source_visitor.dart:595:19: Error: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'.
  - 'ClassDeclaration' is from 'package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.2.0/lib/src/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'macroKeyword'.
    modifier(node.macroKeyword);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Facing same issue since today morning.

Comment: There is an issue reported for it: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/1413

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `analyzer: ^5.11.1` to your `dev_dependencies` and run the following:

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

dart run build_runner build
```

Note: If the analyzer version 5.11.1 doesn't work for you, try changing the version and it will work. You can check for the version here https://pub.dev/packages/analyzer/changelog

Comment: Will work, but this is not a root case of this error. Problem is in dart_style package. It is even written in error provided by OP

Comment: This may work temporarily, but when analyzer publishes 5.11.2 that updates dart_style to 2.3.5, it still will break. @Thioby published a fix that will keep working.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR: Upgrade your packages again and you should get a fixed dart_style.**

Hi, it's me. I'm the problem.

A while back, I added support to dart_style for formatting (currently experimental) code using the upcoming `macro` keyword. When I did that, I forgot to update the analyzer constraint to ensure that dart_style only uses versions of the analyzer that have `ClassDeclaration.macroKeyword` in its public API.

Then I published dart_style 2.3.5 yesterday with that use of `macroKeyword` and the bad analyzer constraint. Oops. :(

I just published a new 2.3.6 version of dart_style which has the same analyzer constraint but doesn't have a compile error on `macroKeyword`. Since it uses the same analyzer constraint, anyone on the old broken 2.3.5 version of dart_style should be able to upgrade to the fixed version by running `dart pub upgrade` (or `flutter pub ugprade` or however else you generally upgrade your packages).

Sorry for the pain.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to lower analyzer version. It does not make any sense.

dart_style library was updated to version 2.3.5.

just lower version `dart_style` to `2.3.4`

Add `dart_style: 2.3.4` to your `dev_dependencies` and run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run build_runner ...
```

Answer (score -1):

It was failing on CI and working fine on local. Updating to the latest version 3.19.2 on CI worked and resolve this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I occurred the same issue, and I set `dart_style` to `2.3.4` then solved it