# Failed to build build_runner:build_runner: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner, flutter-analyzer

I am using Flutter 3.13.1

Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0

Not able to build instead throws an error:

`build_runner:build_runner: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'`

```
    Flutter Compile build runner
    
    Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
    
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_style-2.3.5/lib/src/front_end/ast_node_visitor.dart:251:16: Error: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'.
             - 'ClassDeclaration' is from 'package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.2.0/lib/src/dart/ast/ast.dart').
            Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'macroKeyword'.
                      node.macroKeyword,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/dart_style-2.3.5/lib/src/source_visitor.dart:595:19: Error: The getter 'macroKeyword' isn't defined for the class 'ClassDeclaration'.
             - 'ClassDeclaration' is from 'package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/analyzer-6.2.0/lib/src/dart/ast/ast.dart').
            Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'macroKeyword'.
                modifier(node.macroKeyword);
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: turns out this is a duplicate question refer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78079753/build-runner-showing-error-the-getter-macrokeyword-isnt-defined-for-the-class